# Extract icons out of an SVG sprite

Tags: inkscape, svg, icon, sprite

I have an SVG image sprite with a lot of icons inside it

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/adwaita-icon-theme/blob/master/src/symbolic/gnome-stencils.svg

Is there any method available or a website where we can import these as individual SVGs ?

I do not have Illustrator and will have to use Inkscape for this purpose. It is ok to use a CLI method as I am on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Try https://gitlab.com/su-v/inx-exportobjects

Comment: Works great. But need to terminate via task manager. After converting fine, it refuses to close. Takes a bit of time as well. Trying to give you feedback. :)

Comment: Didn't know it had that issue, thanks!